# Manipulating data from a list of dictionaries (Google API Distance Matrix)

Tags: python, list, dictionary, google-distancematrix-api

I need a help. I am using Google API Distance Matrix and Python 3.5 to find out the closest point from another point. I have the list of dictionaries below and I would like to have a output like:

"Origin 1: the closest destination is Destination 1 (1504 m)"

"Origin 2: the closest destination is Destination 1 (2703 m)"

So on..

Any ideia how can I obtain this output?

```
response=[{'rows': [{'elements': [{'distance': {'text': '1.5 km', 'value': 1504},\
'duration': {'text': '4 mins', 'value': 247}, 'status': 'OK'}]}],\
'origin_addresses': ['Origin 1'], 'destination_addresses': ['Destination 1'], 'status': 'OK'},\
{'rows': [{'elements': [{'distance': {'text': '2.7 km', 'value': 2703},\
'duration': {'text': '7 mins', 'value': 430}, 'status': 'OK'}]}],\
'origin_addresses': ['Origin 2'], 'destination_addresses': ['Destination 1'], 'status': 'OK'},\
{'rows': [{'elements': [{'distance': {'text': '4.8 km', 'value': 4753},\
'duration': {'text': '10 mins', 'value': 586}, 'status': 'OK'}]}],\
'origin_addresses': ['Origin 1'], 'destination_addresses': ['Destination  2'], 'status': 'OK'},\
{'rows': [{'elements': [{'distance': {'text': '6.0 km', 'value': 5952},\
'duration': {'text': '13 mins', 'value': 769}, 'status': 'OK'}]}],\
'origin_addresses': ['Origin 2'], 'destination_addresses': ['Destination 2'], 'status': 'OK'}]\
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code that will find the shortest distance from each origin and then display the result as per the example formatting:

```py
from collections import OrderedDict

def find_closest(distances):
    closest = OrderedDict()
    for distance in distances:
        origin = distance['origin_addresses'][0]
        destination = distance['destination_addresses'][0]
        value = distance['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']['value']

        if origin not in closest or value < closest[origin][1]:
            closest[origin] = (destination, value)

    return closest

def format_closest(closest):
    for origin, (destination, value) in closest.items():
        yield "%s: the closest destination is %s (%d m)" % (origin, destination, value)

for line in format_closest(find_closest(response)):
    print(line)
```

Note that I have used OrderedDict in order to retain the ordering found in your response. If this doesn't matter to you, you can replace `OrderedDict()` with `{}` .

For a list of the formatted results simply use:

```py
list(format_closest(find_closest(response)))
```

Comment: I think something is missing here because first I have to find out the closest destination (smallest value of 'value' in: 'distance': {'text': '2.7 km', 'value':  ).Your code returns all combination of destinations and origins. And I just want the closest one. The code above is just a sample. Sometimes I have 10 origin and 50 destinations.

Comment: @GuyBitencourt yes it wasn't obvious from your initial question that the response required further processing, so the previous code did not attempt to do that. I have updated the code to satisfy this requirement.

Comment: Perfect! Your code is very clear and easy to understand. Thanks a lot!